# Don't get data from firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, chat

Well guys, can anybody explain to me why I can't read the data from the firestore? I've read the documentation and reviewed the path several times, but still can't see it. I'm doing on ionic

```
   getChat(chatId){
        const chatRoom = this.firestore.collection('/business/').doc(chatId);
        const room = chatRoom.get();
        console.log(room);
      }

Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
operator: ObserveOnOperator {scheduler: ɵZoneScheduler, delay: 0}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: And what is wrong here? It returns an observable

Answer (score 1):

try this: after copy this code check all  brackets and 'chatId' is correct

```
getChat(chatId){
        const chatRoom = this.firestore.collection('/business/').doc(chatId);
        const room = chatRoom.get().subscribe(o => {
             console.log(k.data());              
        })
      }
```

Comment: VizaintProperty 'forEach' does not exist on type 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'

Comment: My fault i modify my answer try now